# Why can't I load html content (from a php file) inside the page?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I want the content of the page chosen by select to be loaded into the ajax-container div, but this is not working, why?

index.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>INTRANET - REDES UNIPAM</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <?php include("../menu.php");?>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
            <legend class="scheduler-border">Redes do UNIPAM</legend>
            <select id="mySelect" class="custom-select">
              <option selected>Selecionar rede</option>
              <option><a class="ajax-click" href="index_bloco_a.php">Bloco A</a></option>
              <option><a class="ajax-click" href="index_bloco_b.php">Bloco B</a></option>
            </select>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6" id="ajax-container">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $('.ajax-click').click(function(e) {
      var $clickedElement = $(this),
        pageToLoad = $clickedElement.prop("href");
      $('#ajax-container').load(pageToLoad, function() {
        alert('Conteudo carregado com sucesso');
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  </script>";
</body>

</html>
```

index_bloco_a.php

```
<table width="1500px" border="0" align="center">
        <tr> <td align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA"><titulo><strong>BLOCO A</strong></titulo></td> </tr>
</table>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="8">
        <tr align="center"> <td> <a href="bloco_a_geral.php"> GERAL </a> </td> </tr>
    <tr align="center"> <td> <a href="bloco_a_auto_atendimento.php">AUTO ATENDIMENTO </a> </td> </tr>
    
</table>
```

I wondered if it was because the `<script>` tag was inside a php file, and I tried putting it inside a `<? Php echo "<script> </script>"?>`, But that was just the blank page.

Comment: Plese clarify more, also reduce your code. You have posted the whole code. Try to post only problem related code

Comment: It would be `href="/index_bloco_a.php"` if `index_bloco_a.php` located on your root

Comment: @sta I only removed the absolute path here in the post, but in the original code is the absolute path in href.

Comment: I suggest you move`e.preventDefault();` to the start of your functions to stop links from executing if there is an error in the script

Comment: Please don't rewrite your code here. Just do a copy/paste of the actual code and leave it as is (you can remove code that's not relevant, but don't change the code you leave in the post). It's pretty common that people introduce new bugs/errors when rewriting it for SO, which just makes us waste time pointing out issues that doesn't even exist in your real code.

Comment: Do you get a response from the server on click?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to load jQuery BEFORE bootstrap
2. you want to remove the `";` from `</script>";`
3. Selects cannot contain links

This will work better

```js
$("#mySelect").on("change", function() {
  const pageToLoad = this.value;
  if (pageToLoad) {
    $('#ajax-container').load(pageToLoad, function() {
      console.log('Conteudo carregado com sucesso');
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" class="custom-select">
  <option value="" selected>Selecionar rede</option>
  <option value="index_bloco_a.php">Bloco A</option>
  <option value="index_bloco_b.php">Bloco B</option>
</select>
```